# Use char as &str in HashMap

Tags: string, rust, char, type-conversion, lifetime

I want to create a `HashMap` which maps words — a `Vec` of `&str` — and letters of those words each to another. For example, `vec!["ab", "b", "abc"]` will be converted to the following `HashMap`

```
{
    // Letters are keys, words which contain the keys are values
    "a" => ["ab", "abc"],
    "b" => ["ab", "bc", "abc"],
    "c" => ["bc", "abc"],
    // Words are keys, letters which are in the words are values
    "ab" => ["a", "b"],
    "abc" => ["a", "b", "c"],
}
```

I tried this code [[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9f6b06ebc1c24362d7caba20056e2b7e)]:

```rust
let words = vec!["ab", "bc", "abc"];
let mut map: HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>> = HashMap::new();
for word in words.iter() {
    for letter in word.chars() {
        map.entry(letter).or_default().push(word);
        map.entry(word).or_default().push(letter);
    }
}
```

but there is a problem: `letter` is of type `char` but I need a `&str` because `map` accepts only `&str`s as keys. I also tried to convert `letter` to a `&str`:

```rust
for word in words.iter() {
    for letter in word.chars() {
        let letter = letter.to_string()
        // no changes
```

but this code creates a new `String` which has a smaller lifetime than `map`'s one. In other words, `letter` is dropped after the nested `for` loop but and I get compiler error.

How can I use a `char` in `HashMap` which accepts only `&str`s as keys?

Comment: Why would you need `&str` as the key? `char` seems to be a far more natural choice.

Comment: what you said don't make any sense, what do you really want ?

Comment: @Psidom because keys are not single characters but words

Comment: @Stargateur I tried to clarify the question. Check it out again and tell me what you don't understand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would separate the map into two:

- One is `char -> Vec<&str>`. It maps letters to a list of words.
- The second one would be `&str -> Vec<char>`, but I do not know if you really need it: Why not just iterate over the `chars` of a `&str` directly?

  Storing a `Vec<char>` essentially just doubles the amount of memory you use, unless the `Vec<char>` is e.g. sorted in a particular order (which may or may not be necessary).

If you *really want* to keep them in one map, I think it is easier to have a `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>`.

The problem seems to be that `chars` gives you one `char` after another, but what you actually want is a `&str` after another, where each `&str` actually encompasses a single character. I did not find anything like that in the docs for `&str`, but maybe there is something somewhere that iterates like this.

You could work-around it using `matches`:

```
let words = vec!["ab", "bc", "abc"];
let mut map: HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>> = HashMap::new();
for word in words.iter() {
    for letter in word.matches(|_| true) { // iterates over &str's that encompass one single character
        map.entry(letter).or_default().push(word);
        map.entry(word).or_default().push(letter);
    }
}
```